# Import WebEx .arf into Camtasia for Mac as a media file

Tags: video, webex, camtasia

How can one import a WebEx recording (.arf file) into Camtasia 2 for Mac as a media file? I've read https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/203727178-Camtasia-Mac-Formats-able-to-be-imported-to-the-timeline, which lists the supported import formats, of which .arf is clearly not one. Further, that article suggests (for unsupported formats) to just playback the recording and capture it in Camtasia in streaming realtime.

However, there must be a quick way to convert from .arf to another format that is supported for import into Camtasia (sometimes the videos I need to convert are hours long).

Comment: Supposedly there is a Webex utility to convert ARF to WMV and then you can use Screenflow to convert from WMV to MOV which Camtasia can read. Sounds difficult and I wonder how much of the original recording quality gets lost in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebEx network recording player to convert .arf file into .mp4 file. Which you can import into Camtasia 2.

To install webex network recording player can be downloaded from here, http://www.webex.com/play-webex-recording.html

Comment: I installed the webex network recording player WBS31 software, but the ARF file I have opened does not have any option to covert or save as another format.

Comment: This option is only available to Windows Network player and not for Mac.